# What is org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet?

Tags: java, web-services, testing, glassfish

I searched about javadoc or some other documentation of the *org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet* but there are only non-official links. So what is that class? Why and how it can be used for testing webservices?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.webservices/jsr109-impl/3.0/org/glassfish/webservices/monitoring/WebServiceTesterServlet.java) it looks to be a utility servlet for testing webservices as the name would imply. As far as how to use it? Probably best to play with it by creating an instance and playing with it some. It looks like it's designed for easy local testing, one of the constructors takes an endpoint:

```
public ￼WebServiceTesterServlet(WebServiceEndpoint ep) {
     svcEP = ep;
}
```

Read some of the comments in the source code, it seems to explain what most of the methods are for. The source itself is relatively easy to follow. I'm not sure how useful the class is overall for testing webservices but something like [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/) is very useful for web services testing.